# HTML content display limited lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, extjs

How to display news items which comes from database on a web page limiting the number of lines to 3.

The news content is in html format for example

```
<p><span style="font-family: HelveticaNeue LT 77 BdCn;"><span style="font-size: large;">The average house price&amp;nbsp;up by 0.3% in May</span></span></p>
<p><span style="font-family: HelveticaNeue LT 55 Roman;"><span style="font-size: small;">compared to the previous month <br />but fell 1.2% compared to May 2010</span></span></p>
<p><span style="font-family: HelveticaNeue LT 55 Roman;"><span style="font-size: small;"></span></span><span style="font-family: HelveticaNeue LT 55 Roman;"><span style="font-size: small;"><a href="http://www.nationwide.co.uk/hpi/historical/May_2011.pdf" title="Nationwide House Price Index">Nationwide House Price Index</a></span></span></p>
```

How can i display first three lines only from the above html news by using java script/css and append ... at the end.

I tried by setting height and overflow on div element that wraps the above news content but that will crop the bottom line of text depending upon the font or browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the most reliable way to do this would be to set the `line-height` property (to whatever looks best to you), then setting the `height` property to 3 times the value you used for the `line-height` property.  Then, just use the `overflow` property accordingly, like you've said.

For example:

```
.newsItems {
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 3.6em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you use font-relative values for this (eg: `line-height: 1.2em;  height:3.6em;`).  Now, if you change the font-size (or the user overrides your font choices), it'll still work the way you want it to.

Comment: I do not have control over news content as user can use any font or size or bold etc..

Comment: If the whole thing is one font and font-size (that the user can select), then using `em` should work.  I've updated my example to reflect this, as @Lee's suggestion is probably more correct in general.  If the user can change the font and font-size at any point mid-sentence, then getting exactly three lines will be difficult (I think impossible) to achieve using pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the font, you can set the height of the div appropriately.  The simple answer is to set the height to 3em, though you'll probably still need some tweaking.